# curl_multi for Indy (IdHTTP)?

Tags: delphi, curl, delphi-xe2, libcurl, indy

How can I do curl_multi in Delphi with Indy IdHTTP ? I mean multiple requests just like in PHP.. but instead of using cURL I will use Indy.

> Curl_multi is basicly multiple HTTP requests in parallel within a single thread

It can be any other library aswell. Because to my knowledge CurlPas hasn't been updated since 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple instances of IdHTTP, each in it's own thread.

### Update

To clarify: Create a TThread subclass. In the TThread execute, pick up one requested URL, create one IdHttp and service it. You can have multiple such threads going in parallel. This means your HTTP requests are being serviced in parallel, just like curl.

Comment: Just be careful of not DOS'ing yourself (been there, done that)